# Should I change dsym file uploading script when migrated from Fabric to Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

Recently I have migrated from Fabric to Firebase for one of my iOS apps using migration link shown in Fabric dashboard. All the crashes are showing fine in the Firebase Console. Should I change dsym file uploading script for next release or previous dsym file uploading script will still work?

#### My current uploading script

```
./upload-symbols -a ${vars.getValue("fabric_api")} -p ios MyApp.app.dSYM
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no necessary changes at this time. However when you do adopt the new Firebase Crashlytics SDKs (released this week into Beta) you will need to change this to no longer include your Fabric API key.